# A series of equivalences for bounded sets in a vector space

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(X,\|\;\|)$ be a vector space over $K\;(\Bbb R\text{  or  }\Bbb C)$ and let $A\subseteq X$ be non-empty. I want to prove the following are equivalent:

$$
(a)\;\; A\text{  is bounded}\\
(b)\;\;\forall\text{ neighborhood } U\text{ of } 0,\exists\epsilon>0\text{ s.t. }aA\subset U\;\forall a\in K\text{ with }|a|<\epsilon\\
(c)\;\text{ If } D\subset A\Rightarrow D\text{ is bounded}\\
(d)\;\forall \{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\subseteq A\Rightarrow\;\lim_{n\to\infty} \alpha_nx_n=0\;\;\forall\{\alpha_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset K\text{ s.t. } \lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha_n=0
$$
I've already proved that$\;\;(a)\Rightarrow (b)\Rightarrow (c)\Rightarrow (d)$ and got stucked trying to prove that $(d)\Rightarrow (a)$. I read that if every sequence of $A$ is bounded I can get any convergent subsequence from it and with this show that $A$ is bounded but I haven't understood the idea quite good since I only know that $\{\alpha_nx_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and $\{\alpha_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ are bounded. Any ideas how to continue with this one would be appreciated. Also if you have a better a approach than this would appreciate it.

Comment: $(b)$ is the definition of a bounded set in a topological vector space. For the proof of $(d) \implies (a)$, suppose $A$ is not bounded, and show that $(d)$ fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Assume that $A$ is not bounded. Then for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ you find $x_{n}\in A$ such that $\|x_n\|>n$. Now take a sequence $(a_n)\subseteq K$ such that $|a_n|=\frac{1}{n}$. Then what is $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n a_n$ ? (Or more likely, what is it not)

Comment: Thanks! I see it now. Clearly $$\|a_nx_n\|>1\;\;\forall n\in\Bbb N$$
So this implies that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_nx_n\neq0,\text{   if exists}$$
which contradicts the fact that $(a_nx_n)$ should converge to 0

Comment: @Arnulf. Great!